# Is it possible to send an html document to a server?

Tags: android, html, httpurlconnection

Is it possible to send a full html document to a server using `HttpURLConnection` in android ?

Comment: do you mean Sending a File to Remote Server whether it was html or anything else?

Comment: In meant a string containing html, but also the idea of the file seems more feasible... but in that case should I have to save a file into the memory whenever I want to do so?

Comment: no you don't have to save it and it is actually a proper question to ask about transferring files rather than html documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AhmadAlsanie Your were right, actually sending a file to a remote server it's a better idea and this [post](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk) helped me with what I wanted to do... Thanks a lot !